# Ошибка при установке библиотеки AdaFruit-BBIO | Python

Tags: python, библиотеки

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку AdaFruit-BBIO для python 3.7. При установке выдает группу однотипных ошибок типа:

```
"/usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/source/py_gpio.o:/tmp/pip-install-6079ueb8/adafruit-bbio_dbd88cc1ba6841c8b5c371dc3fd24f85/source/constants.h:15: повторное определение «version»; 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/source/constants.o:/tmp/pip-install-6079ueb8/adafruit-bbio_dbd88cc1ba6841c8b5c371dc3fd24f85/source/constants.h:15: здесь первое определение"
```

Таких ошибок много порядка 15 штук различия только в названиях того, что повторно определяется: `«version»`,  `«both_edge»`,  `«falling_edge»` и т.д.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть причина и как исправить.
Спасибо.